# Scrolling through list elements doesn't start on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a script that will scroll through list elements by clicking on a "previous" and "next" link. When the user first clicks on the "next" button, they have to click twice before the second list element is displayed. The "previous" link works just fine but how can fix my script to where the user only has to click once on the "next" button?

http://jsfiddle.net/S79qp/290/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put `active` on the first element by default.

```
<li class="first active none">Ferrari</li>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help! I'll accept your answer as soon as the time limit is up.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that on the first click on "next", there is no element with the class `.active`, consequently `$('.active')` won't find anything and `$('.active').next().length` will be 0, so the first element will be given the class `.active`.

The solution add the class `.active` to the first element that is initially shown, which will make the class `.first` obsolete: http://jsfiddle.net/hx4AD/